# cannot open and read a file, picked by file_picker, in Flutter desktop on MacOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to open a file but i allways get error 1.
I'm using macos, and developing for macos.
any help on how i can open a fil in flutter without getting error?

i tried this:

```
void getAPI() {
  var url = "https://controller.test.io/v1/";
  SecurityContext context = SecurityContext();
  context.setTrustedCertificates("/Users/me/keys/crtfile");
  context.usePrivateKey("/Users/me/keys/keyfile");
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(context: context);
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
      .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
      print(contents);
    });
  });
}
```

but i get this:

```
Cannot open file, path = '/Users/me/keys/crtfile' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

Comment: @Vaidarbhi
i have added to DebugProfile.entitlements

    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>

this is all i need no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch AppSandbox off (remove `com.apple.security.app-sandbox` from your entitlements files), and the app won't make extra security checks.

If you still want to have AppSandbox on, then you should also add to your entitlements files:

```xml
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
<true/>
```

and pick this file with standard Open File Dialog, which gives RW permissions to only user selected files.

```dart
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
result?.files.first.path; // the OS will grant access to this file
```

Comment: nope doesn't work. still gives error. in my case it's `flutter: ProcessException: Operation not permitted Command: which osascript`